# Align RadioButtons in RadioGroup (created by code) in android

Tags: android, radio-button, alignment, radio-group

In my app I need to create a `RadioGroup` with 2 `RadioButtons` by code. I need to align the RadioButtons inside the `RadioGroup`, one to the left, and the other to the right part of `RadioGruop`. I know that if I add the radio-buttons to a LinearLayout these will solve this problem but in this case the property of RadioGroup, that only one RadioButton is checked at a time is not anymore available.
Here is my code :

```
 TableRow.LayoutParams lp_radio1 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                                                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
TableRow.LayoutParams lp_radio2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                                                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
TableRow.LayoutParams lp_radiogr = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                                                width, height);
    lp_radio1.setMargins(left, left, top2, 0);
    lp_radio1.gravity=Gravity.LEFT;
    lp_radio1.weight=1;
    lp_radio2.setMargins(left, left, top2, 0);
    lp_radio2.gravity=Gravity.RIGHT;
    lp_radio2.weight=1;
```

---

```
    product_radiogroup = new RadioGroup(viewToLoad.getContext()); 
           product_radiogroup.setLayoutParams(lp_radiogr);                                             product_radiogroup.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);                                   product_radiogroup.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.radio_group_background);
    product_radiobuttonYES = new RadioButton(viewToLoad.getContext());
    product_radiobuttonYES.setLayoutParams(lp_radio1); 

product_radiobuttonYES.setTextColor(R.color.medium_gray);        
    product_radiobuttonNO = new RadioButton(viewToLoad.getContext());
    product_radiobuttonNO.setLayoutParams(lp_radio2);
    product_radiobuttonNO.setTextColor(R.color.medium_gray);
    product_radiogroup.addView(product_radiobuttonYES);
    product_radiogroup.addView(product_radiobuttonNO);
```

and here is my result :

[image]

Has anyone any idea how to solve this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

i don't think this solution is a nice one, but since you know the exact `width` and `height` of your `radiogroup`, just set the `width` of your `radiobutton` to `width/2` instead of `wrap_content` and other attributes, such as `weight` and `gravity` on `lp_radio1` and `lp_radio2` can be removed.